# Trying to fing span element by class and text on selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to click on Administration panel. span contain class and text. error saying unable to locate element.

HTML:

```
<div class="item-inner">
      <span class="title"> Administration </span>
      <i class="icon-arrow"></i>
</div>
```

C# code:

```
var admi = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'title')][contains(text(),'Administration')]"));
admi.Click();
```

Comment: Check if the HTML snippet you've posted is within a `frame` tag. You need to switch to it by adding something like this `driver.switchTo().frame(0);`.

Comment: Yes, As said in above comment, Administration span must be within `frame`  tag. As there can not be any other reason for not finding element. I tried with _ONLY_ above code, it is finding element with `cssSelector` as well as given `xpath`.